# update div in index view after calling update method in ajax in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a page with list of posts and I use `ajax` for pagination using `will_paginate` and I have a `"Like" button` near by each post. If the user clicks the "Like" button then I need to `update` the count of likes in my table and I want to change the "Like" button to `"Dislike"`.

Say, for example if I am in the second page of the post and I click on the "Like" button I would need to call my update method and how could I bring back to the same page and change the button using ajax.

I could possibly do if my update logic is in the same index method but how could I replace the content in the `index.html.erb` if my logic resides in the `update` method.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: if you are not redirecting it and updating everything by ajax then wont be you be still at the same page?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. If I click on the like button then it would update and how will the respond as js of update method would be replacing the button of index.html.erb

Comment: oh i thought you were updating it by ajax and by the way i think you should update it by an ajax request as that should be correct flow else you'll somehow have to call the paginate and even then it will only show your correct page not the updated question.

Comment: Yes, I am updating by Ajax but I still cannot understand how I could change the button. Sorry if I am not clear. Could you please help me with some code samples.

Comment: Can you post your code which is executing in ajax call

Comment: Sorry. Right now I am using my phone to reply. So, I can't post my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question says:

`Say, for example if I am in the second page of the post and I click on the "Like" button I would need to call my update method and how could I bring back to the same page and change the button using ajax.`

Lets go through the steps one by one:

a. Create a **route for your custom method** where you'll update it and it has to be a **`post`** route since we *want to send the post id which is to be updated*

```
post '/update_post/:id' => "your_controller#update_post", as: :update_post
```

b. Create **a link:**

```
<%= link_to "Like", update_post_path(post.id),id: "post_#{post.id}",method: :post %>
```

c. Have a **respond_to block** in your method and **update your post:**

```
def update_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  # update your post here
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{} #this will allow you to have update_post.js.erb in your view
  end
end
```

d. Update **your link** in update.js.erb:

```
$("#post_<%= @post.id %>").text("Dislike");
```

Now since *we are updating your link and post by ajax you will remain at same page and you wont have to worry about pagination*. For more information refer to [**`Working with javascript in rails`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. What I was thinking is how could the index view be updated from update.js.erb.

Comment: Why do you want to update your index view? It's an ajax request so user will remain at current page and hence at his/her post.