# Not receiving ajax events from Devise login form on Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I'm having trouble with receiving the various classes of ajax events related to the sign in form from Devise in Rails 4.

Here's the standard Devise sign in form that I modified with the remote attribute to submit via ajax:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), remote: true, format: :json) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email%><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'  %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control'  %>
    </div>
    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <%= f.label :remember_me %>
      </div>
    <% end -%>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit "Sign in", id: 'sign-in', class: 'btn btn-primary pull-right' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm binding to the ajax events using jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#new_user').ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) { console.log('completed'); });
});
```

It looks like the event gets registered, and I even re-registered it in the Chrome javascript console after the page had loaded.  All appears to have been set up correctly, but when I submit the form, and get a response from the server, the event isn't fired.

Any thoughts on what I've done incorrectly?

UPDATE: In fact, I can't get ajax events on any rails forms with a remote: true attribute set.  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with Devise.

Here's some info about versions of seemingly relevant stuff:

- jquery-rails (3.1.1)
- rails (4.1.1)

Comment: you have your js code in which file?

Comment: A separate file, login.js.  I ensured that the code has run, as it hit the breakpoint I set in Chrome.

Comment: why aren't you using rails way of doing ajax by having a js.erb template?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the pattern.  I've only been doing rails for about a year, so I'm still a bit green.  Would it have made a difference?

Comment: I read over [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127697/js-erb-vs-js) to get an idea of what you're talking about.  I could have done it that way, but it doesn't sound like it would make a difference.

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613684/how-to-use-js-file-within-view-folder/24613978#24613978 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468146/update-div-in-index-view-after-calling-update-method-in-ajax-in-rails/24470227#24470227 to get an idea of how to use it. You won't need to bind your ajaxsuccess event and you can directly use your js inside template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a really dumb issue.  application.js includes jQuery, but I also had a javascript include tag for a later version of jQuery within my application.html.erb layout.

Moral of the story: don't double include jQuery... weird things happen.

Thanks to all those who tried to lend a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding it to the ajax:complete or ajax:success event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#new_user').bind("ajax:complete", function(event, xhr, settings) { console.log('completed');
});
```

Comment: Just tried, no luck.  Though, after reviewing the jQuery documentation for ajaxComplete(), I was incorrect in trying to call it on a selected element.

Per jQuery docs:
As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document.